# How to change post status link order(priority) on cpt listing page

Tags: custom-post-types, post-status

On a custom post type listing page the registered post statuses are listed as links above the post lists. I've a situation where custom registered post types are showing after 'trash' and I still want trash to be the last listed link.

What can I do? It's hard to find documentation on this because the of the complex terminology. Anyall help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can use this filter to alter the priority of the post_status links:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5c6b63d3a6874743542d6cede307c98ee370af23/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L378

```
$views = apply_filters( "views_{$this->screen->id}", $views );
```

If your custom post type is 'inbound-email' then the applied filter will look like this:

```
    add_filter( 'views_edit-inbound-email' , 'function_to_filter_priority' );
    /**
     * rebuild priority of post status links
     * @param ARRAY $links
     * @return ARRAY $new_links
     */
    function function_to_filter_priority( $links ) {
        $new_links['all'] = $links['all'];

        if (isset($links['draft'])) {
            $new_links['draft'] =  $links['draft'];
        }
        if (isset($links['pending'])) {
            $new_links['pending'] =  $links['pending'];
        }
        if (isset($links['sent'])) {
            $new_links['sent'] =  $links['sent'];
        }
        if (isset($links['automated'])) {
            $new_links['automated'] =  $links['automated'];
        }
        if (isset($links['trash'])) {
            $new_links['trash'] =  $links['trash'];
        }

        return $new_links;
    }
```